# How to align divs so top right of child touches bottom left of parent?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-position

I am trying to create a messages box on my site, so that when user clicks inbox icon a box appears with the messages. Similar to how stackoverflow does this. Stackoverflow does this by having a div outside the ordered list that comprises inbox, achievements, etc, and then absolutely positioning that div so that it appears to drop from the inbox icon.

I am trying to do likewise, but I want the messages box to be a child of the list item.

```css
.list {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

div.messages {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<ol class="list">
  <ul> inbox
    <div class="messages"> some message<br> blah blah another message
    </div>
  </ul>
  <ul> another </ul>
</ol>
```

Is there a simple way to assure that the top right of the message box touches the bottom left of the list item, regardless of width of the message box?

Maybe I am thinking about this wrong and this really isn't meant to be a parent-child situation (since what I am trying to do is essentially place the child outside the parent...). But for conceptual organization of my site's sections I really do want to handle this as child in parent).

Comment: Your code is pretty thin.  Do you know the width of the message box? Do you know the height? If not, are you willing to use javascript?  If you DO know the width / height, it's pretty simple.

Comment: I see your using flexbox which makes this a little tricky. Check out css-grid. css-grid will make this job super super easy.

Comment: Hi, I am willing to use javascript, and in fact that is how I plan on displaying/hiding the box (using display:block and display:hide). I suppose I can set fixed width of the message box, but height will change. Thanks, Brian

Comment: Ahh, ok, so css-grid essentially seems like tables. Maybe I will give that a try. Thanks!

Comment: BTW, your HTML is invalid. Only `<li>` elements may be children of `<ul>` elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

like this

```js
 $(".nav_link").on('click',function() {

   $(this).next('.container').addClass("block_container");
 })
```

```css
    .list {
       display: inline-block
       position: relative;
    }
    li{
        list-style: none;
    }
    .list .dropdown_ancker{
       display: inline-block;
       width: 50px;
       background-color: red;
        list-style: none;
        margin-right: 12px;
       position: relative;
    }
    .container{
        position: absolute;
        display: none;

      }
      .block_container{
        display: block;

      }

      .container{
      background-color: green;
      right:50px;

      }

      .container li{
        color: #252525;
        padding: 12px 20px;


      }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol class = "list"> 

       <li class="dropdown_ancker">another</li>
       <li class="dropdown_ancker">
        <span class="nav_link">inbox</span>
        <ul class="container">
          <li class="m">something</li>
          <li class="m">something</li>
        </ul>

       </li><!--
    --><li class="dropdown_ancker">another</li>
    </ol>
```

.container right= dropdown_ancker width

Comment: This doesn't seem to fit OP's requirements. You have the top left of the child, instead of the top right, touching the bottom left of the parent.

Comment: is this ok @TylerH

Comment: you can use jQ `.toggleClass()` @Brian

Comment: Ok, I see how I can adjust so top right of box touches bottom left of parent. Thanks. I will have to think about what this will imply for viewing on cell phone screen. Maybe I need media query or maybe css3 has some other property (flex or something) that will help towards that end. Thanks again, Brian

Comment: media query change the css of `. container` @Brian

Comment: on click  since you can't hover on the link 'top right of the message box touches the bottom left' @TylerH

Answer (score 2):

Your parent `ul` should have `position: relative;` as well, then you can set the `right: 0;` to your dropdown `div.messages`. Also, I don't see a need to set 
`.list` as a `flexbox` here.

```css
.list {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

div.messages {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  border: 1px solid blue; /*for testing only, easier to see the element*/
}

ul {
  border: 1px solid red; /*for testing only, easier to see the element*/
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

li {
  list-style: none; /*to remove the bullet symbol from li*/
}
```

```html
<ol class="list">
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>
        inbox
        <div class="messages"> some message<br> blahblahblahblah blah another message
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>another</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you know how to use proper html structure, element positioning, css adjustments and jquery, you can achieve this. Here is a sample i created for you. It uses a simple `ul` with `menu-box` div after each `li` to achieve the desired result.

```js
$(function(){
  
 $('.main-menu li > a').click(function(){
    $('.menu-box').hide();
    $(this).next().show();
  });
  
  $(document).mouseup(function(e) 
{
    var container = $(".menu-box");

    // if the target of the click isn't the container nor a descendant of the container
    if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) 
    {
        container.hide();
    }
});
  
});
```

```css
@import url(//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css);

body{
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
}

.fa {
position: relative;
display: table-cell;
width: 60px;
height: 40px;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
font-size:25px;
}

.main-menu{
  width:100vw;
  height:38px;
  text-align:center;
}

.main-menu>ul {
margin:10px;
  display:inline-block;
}

.main-menu li {
position:relative;
display:block;
width:60px;
float:left;
}

.main-menu li>a {
position:relative;
display:table;
border-collapse:collapse;
border-spacing:0;
color:#999;
font-family: arial;
font-size: 16px;
text-decoration:none;
border:1px solid black;
}

.menu-box{
background:gray;
border:1px solid black;
width:250px;
height:350px; /*Set as necesary or auto based on content*/
overflow:hidden;
z-index:1000;
display:none;
margin-top:-1px;
position:absolute;
/*left:0*/  /* Use this if your want to align box to the left*/
right:60px; /* width of icon can be set in jQuery if dynamic */
}

.hidden{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Click on any icon</h2>
<nav class="main-menu">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a>
                        <i class="fa fa-home fa-2x"></i>
                    </a>
                  <div class="menu-box"></div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-laptop fa-2x"></i>
                    </a>
                    <div class="menu-box"></div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                       <i class="fa fa-list fa-2x"></i>
                    </a>
                    <div class="menu-box"></div>
                </li>
            </ul>
  </nav>
```

Hope this helps. Happy Coding. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I am far more comfortable with backend dev and seeing these sorts of examples from you and others is really clearing things up and helping improve my front end skills. For small widths, would I just use media query and set menu-box to relative position?

Comment: You can try on that sure. If you can give me a specific structure on what your thinking then i can help out.

Comment: Hi Nasir, my site is guitar-dreams.com. The notifications would be at upper right next to Home menu item. I have things working somewhat on my local environment, but trying to get formatting of the notifications window, with header, etc, and other styling properties of other elements are just making it a pain. Anyway, don't go too much out of your way. I actually posted a job request on upwork since I am trying to spend less time on dev and more time playing guitar!

Comment: That is great. I am a manager in a virtual staffing company in the US. If you want then i can get you a resource to satisfy your development needs. Let me know or send me email on nasirtariq@gmail.com if/when you have any development need that you dont want to do yourself and want to know more. Happy coding and guitar'ing :)